# How can I have a listing page for categorized content in Hugo?

Tags: hugo, static-site

I want to categorize some *events* like *meetups* and *conferences*.

I want to have a page on `/events` where I can see **all** events and `/events/meetups` where I can see all *meetups*.

My problem is that if I organize my pages in a *section* named **events** and I put my markdown files in the two folders *meetups* and *conferences* I will be able to see them under `/events/conferences` and `/events/meetups` respectively but the `/events` page will be empty.

What I'd like to achieve is that if I have for example `conf A`, `conf B`, `meetup A` and `meetup B` I'd like to see `conf A` and `conf B` under `/events` and `/events/conferences` and `meetup A` and `meetup B` under `/events` and `/meetups` respectively.

I tried creating an `events` taxonomy for this but then the sections **clash** with the taxonomy so it did not work. How can I achieve something like this? Is there a best practice for this kind of content organization?

Comment: This page contains a video that explains how to do this: https://gohugo.io/content-management/taxonomies/

Comment: I think that 'conference' and 'meetup' should be categories of events.

Comment: Nevermind I reverted back to using Jekyll.

Answer (score 0):

Hugo allows you to define your own taxonomies, in this case you could call a taxonomy *event* and then assign your meetups and conferences the event type in the frontmatter.

So first you add

```
taxonomies:
  event: "events"
```

to your website configuration yaml.

And then in the frontmatter of your markdown file called something like `meetup-a.md` you add:

```
---
...
events: [meetups]
...
---
```

Your *meetup A* will now be listed under /events/ (actually a whole list of all event types and the pages that belong to it) and then all meetups under /events/meetups. Hugo regenerates these pages for you all the time, based on what you set in the front matter of your pages.

Comment: Thanks! I've switched back to Jekyll since though.